# Как добавить элемент в другой page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

Можно ли средствами js (Jquery), добавить элемент в другой html? Допустим JS функция обрабатывается на 1.html, в этой функции создаю select и добавляю его в  который находиться в 2.html.

Как это реализуемо ?

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, только если одно окно было открыто из JS другого:

```
w2 = window.open(....);
w2.xxxx();
```

Обращаться к предку тоже можно:

```
window.opener.xxxx();
```

Если это 2 независимых окна с разными страницами, то контекст исполнения у них будет независим друг от друга.

Answer (score 0):

Никак. JavaScipt работает в контексте страницы. Чтобы что то изменилось в другой страницы, необходимо чтобы там отработал свой скрипт

Answer (score 0):

Только посредством сервера. С помощью js Вы можете послать запрос на смену контента (сервер как-то запоминает, что было выбрано). На второй странице динамически меняем контент в зависимости от запомненных данных.